# HTML5 get coordinates of arc's end

Tags: javascript, html

If we draw an arc, how can we get coordinates of arc's end (last point) with respect to the center.

Comment: Do you mean drawing an arc using `<canvas>`? Can you provide some code or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, using <canvas>. var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas1');
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( 0, 0, 20, -180,-140 , false )
ctx.stroke();

Comment: What do you mean with *last point*? All points are at the same distance with respect to the center

Comment: Actually I meant, the point where arc ends (angle = -140)

Comment: Why do you use -140? Angles are in radians, and -140 radians are -8021.409131831525 degrees. If you use degrees, convert them with `radians = (Math.PI/180)*degrees`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/5DdQt/

Use

```
function getPoint(c1,c2,radius,angle){
    return [c1+Math.cos(angle)*radius,c2+Math.sin(angle)*radius];
}
```

- `c1` and `c2` are the coordinates of the center of the arc
- `radius` is the arc's radius
- `angle` is the last point's angle ***in radians***.

Radians = `(degrees * Math.PI) / 180`.

Comment: I was trying to use this code to get points at certain angles of the circle.  I was sending in values 0-2 as my angle but was getting a weird response.  Adding `angle*Math.PI` instead of simply `angle` worked for me.

Comment: Used this for adding labels in a vanilla JS pie chart. Take arithm. mean of start and end angles of the pie slice and a radius smaller than that of the pie. Worked beautifully.